# How to find closed form of this recursive relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Suppose $a_0 = 1 , a_1 = 1$ ,and the recurrence is given by $a_{n+2} = (1 + a_{n+1})/a_n$ , is there a closed form of this recurrence ? If we were to asked to find $x_n$ or some specific value that is .

Comment: Compute $a_n$ for $n=2,\dots,6$.

Comment: But that is not a proper way to get the result isnt ? If i dont know from starting that terms might repeat?

Comment: If you can guess the general term, you can prove it by induction (if you actually guessed correctly)

Comment: So by that we guessed the series is repeating how to find general term ?

Comment: Mathematica says: $a(n)=(\left(2+4 n^2+4 n^3+n^4\right) \bmod 5)=2+4 n^2+4 n^3+n^4-5 \left\lfloor \frac{1}{5} \left(2+4 n^2+4 n^3+n^4\right)\right\rfloor$

Comment: Is it possible to get it not from Mathematica ?

Comment: Hmmm seems like pattern check is okay , thanks